# Place Picker select default position

Tags: android, location

All I want in android is have default position selected. The below code doesnt do the thing, i want the marker to be  on a certain position when user opens the placepicker to select.

```
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
  PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
  final EditText longitude1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
  final EditText latitude1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
  Double lng = Double.parseDouble("0");
  Double lnt = Double.parseDouble("0");
  longitude1.setText("24.7136");
  latitude1.setText("46.6753");
  if(!longitude1.getText().toString().equals("")){
    lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude1.getText().toString());
  }
  if(latitude1.getText().toString().equals("")){
    lnt = Double.parseDouble(latitude1.getText().toString());
  }
  LatLng bottomLeft = new LatLng(lnt ,lng);
  LatLng topRight = new LatLng(lnt ,lng);

  LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(bottomLeft ,topRight);
  builder.setLatLngBounds(bounds);
  startActivityForResult(builder.build((Activity)UpdatePropertyActivity.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see here, You are allowed to give boundry of a area(i.e builder.setLatLngBounds).
So,you can do one thing, give the desired location LatLng in southwest and northeast, like:-

Suppose my desired location="12.980546, 77.646268"

```
LatLngBounds MyDesiredLocation = new LatLngBounds(
                new LatLng(12.980546, 77.646268), new LatLng(12.980546, 77.646268));

        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

        builder.setLatLngBounds(MyDesiredLocation);
        try {
            // for activty
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            // for fragment
            //startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So, this will shrink the boundry to your desired location... Hope it helps,  Try it!!!